# Writing large dataframe to HDF5: RuntimeWarning

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a fairly large dataframe `df` containing 3 columns of type `string`, `integer` and `date`, respectively:

```
strings         object
integers        int64
times           datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

The dataframe has almost 200k rows. I output `df` to an HDF5 file using the following code:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('df.h5', 'w')
store.put('df', df, format='table')
```

however, I get a warning: `RuntimeWarning: Overflow encountered in long_scalars`

I think it is due to the size of the dataframe compared to how much (little) memory I have on my computer.

Is there a smart way to circumvent this issue, or do I simply need a computer with more memory?

Comment: An overflow warning should not have anything to do with running out of memory. It seems that these warnings arise under several circumstances with Pandas (see issues [#183](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/183) and [#14057](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14057), for example), so it might be some internal error. I would try to load the saved data and compare with the original with [`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) (if memory allows...).

Comment: Also, I don't know how big are your strings, but 200k rows should be more than manageable for any current computer.

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of your dataframe including the index?

Comment: Maybe you have a type conversion eg. from uint64 (long) to int64.